# Dual booting two Ubuntu versions

Tags: dual-boot

I want to install two Ubuntu versions on the same system (like dual boot). I'm using Ubuntu 9.10 and I also want to install Ubuntu 10. Please tell me how I might do this, as I don't know enough about Linux.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use the Ubuntu 10.10 CD/USB installer and, when prompted, choose to install side by side with the existing operating system. The process is the same as installing Ubuntu side by side with Windows.

[image]

Please read the full installation instructions [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download). Click 'Show me how' on step 4 of the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

It would be be like dualbooting with windows.Install ubuntu 10 on a seperate partition,and make sure you are using the grub boot loader from ubuntu 10..

Comment: From where i can see the partition of ubuntu.Thanks for reply

Comment: Type **sudo fdisk -l** It will list all partitions in your system..You can see your ubuntu partitions there.

Comment: you may also try 'gparted' . It is a graphical tool for partition management.