# Bootable Ubuntu Install Partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, live-environment

I installed ubuntu on my dad's laptop a year ago and I wanted to install another ubuntu based distro on his laptop . He has no cds or dvds so I thought about making  partition that would pretty much be a copy of the install cd. 
I did the same thing on windows 7 and thanks to easyBCD it wasn't hard to pull off.  So far I tried to create a 1 gig partition with the EXT4 filesystem and extracted the contents of the iso onto that partition.

Do any of you guys know how I could make this work , or any alternative simple solutions?

Comment: Does [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/340156/install-ubuntu-from-iso-image-directly-from-hard-disk-of-a-system-running-linux/340171#340171) help?

Comment: I love you mitch! , that works perfectly!

Comment: It is easier to use a usb stick installer. You can follow this documentation how to create bootable usb stick using "Startup Disc Creator" - http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

Comment: It doesn't seem like that would work with a partition .

Comment: Yes, you don't need your 1GB partition and instead create a bigger partition like 15GB for your new Ubuntu installation.

Now, boot using the USB stick installer and follow the screen instructions. Choose the option to "Install alongside other operating systems". Ubuntu is intelligent enough to detect the spare partition on your hard drive. Ref: http://askubuntu.com/questions/13977/dual-booting-two-ubuntu-versions