# Attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0' after trying to install alongside

Tags: system-installation, grubrescue, boot-repair, ubuntu-gnome

these days i was having problems with the speed of my system Ubuntu gnome 16.04 lts,so i decided to install along side it the same partition to see if it would be better,instead of that installation failed and now i have this problem,and if i try to install again,installation stacked at page that telling me download updates while installing gnome?What i should do?also boot repair keep scanning a lot of time.

Comment: let me start from the begging
At first i had dual boot windows 10 and ubuntu gnome 16.04 lts.Then because of a problem of windows,i installed gnome again and choose erase all and install gnome.Then because i noticed gnome's system speed was too low i decided to install the same version of gnome to another partition to see if things would be better,but when i choosed install along side i had the error that disk had uncorrected errors and i had to go back,instead of that i restart my pc and now i have the problem i told you

Comment: My hard disk has not something i dont want to lose.So if there is a fast solution that will delete all of my data i dont have problem
i just need a quick fix because i need pc for university imediately

Comment: Your partitions are off and please add the steps that led here and the errors also

Answer (score 0):

Take these steps:

1. Clean file system:-

   - Boot into recovery mode
   - Select `fsck` to clean your file system
   - [image]
2. Now if you wish to still `dual boot`.

   - Insert the install USB and follow the instruction and please select to install along side the current OS.

Source:

[Dual booting two Ubuntu versions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13977/dual-booting-two-ubuntu-versions)